# How to escape relevant characters in a string, if it's not already?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file, which I would like to read all lines in to a MySQL database. For this, I wrote a perl script.

Some characters -- mostly `'` and `\` -- need to be escaped. But there are also lines in which these characters are already escaped.

How can I detect whether or not a character is already escaped, and if not, how to escape it? I need a kind of regular expression, which matches `'` but not `\'` or `\` and not `\\`.

Comment: Something like `(?<!\\)[\\'](?![\\'])` [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/eY3iT9/1)?

Comment: This, however, fails, when series of single quotes might rightfully be part of your input: [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/eY3iT9/2).

Comment: Why do you need to escape them?

Comment: There's an important difference between escaping on a character-by-character basis characters that haven't already been escaped; and detecting if an *entire line* has already had at least some escaping done and leaving just those lines untouched. Which do you want?

Comment: Re "How can I detect whether or not a character is already escaped", There's no way to tell if `\'` is already escaped or two characters in need of escaping.

Comment: Could/does your input hold sequences of more than two consecutive backslashes? If so: How should these be handled?

Comment: "How can I detect whether or not a character is already escaped, and if not, how to escape it?" - That's like asking how to detect whether a number (such as 10) is the result of adding two other numbers (such as 7 + 3). There is no meaningful answer.

Comment: @Jim Davis, if i don't escape them, i'll receive lots of MySQL errors. The INSERT statement can otherwise not be executed.

Comment: @Sam Graham: I need a character-by-character based escaping.

Comment: @salim_aliya - You may want to look into using [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values), but that won't help you if something else is doing escaping.  (Unless I'm *entirely* misreading this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be doing, what you are asking for. Search for

```
((?<!\\)\\(?![\\'])|(?<!\\)')
```

and replace with

```
\\\1
```

See it in action: [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/eY3iT9/4).

It combines two search expressions, one for the backslash, and one for the single quote. Each of them looks around to make sure, it's not already (part of) an escape sequence.

It leaves, however, sequences of more than two backslashes untouched. - Which should probably be OK for even numbers of them (considering them escaped). But uneven ones...

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: That will leave `\\\ ` as is.

Comment: @ikegami Right - and I did mention that as soon as I realized: "It leaves, however, sequences of more than two backslashes untouched." But as long as OP doesn't comment, we do not know, whether it is relevant in their context. And the suggested approach might still be acceptable in a two-pass-solution as long as nothing better is being offered.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't really read the answer. But you did claim that it's probably ok, while I think it's definitely not

Comment: @ikegami Well - I read it "Given your input, this should work. But there are cases (beyond what you listed), which it can't cover." -- And I'll be happy to withdraw, if OP adds more detail - ruling out this approach, or/and if somebody hits the nail right on its head. (Unless I'm able to adjust the above appropriately.)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. As i could see it in action at RegEx 101, it seems to work fine. It will take long time until i have tested it in my script, because my text file is about 3GB large. I will then confirm your reply. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you ask. Essentially it searches for all four strings in question, in decreasing order of length so that it finds escaped sequences first, and escapes just the solitary characters leaving the already-escaped matches untouched

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = q{which matches ' but not \' or \ and not \\\\.};

say $s;

$s =~ s/(\\\\|\\')|(\\|')/$1 ? $1 : "\\$2"/eg;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
which matches ' but not \' or \ and not \\.
which matches \' but not \' or \\ and not \\.
```